# css processing order of stylesheets

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware of that styles are applied in cascading order, but starting with me working with the materialize framework I have some problems with cascading my styles.
The stylesheets are loaded as I referenced them in my html page:

1. materialize.css
2. login.css

[image]

when I look at how they are applied at the DOM I see that they are not applied in the order they are loaded.

1. Materialize (line 2587)
2. login
3. materialize (line 6701)

[image]

I assume this behavior is caused by the event driven, non blocking model of Javascript/BrowserEngine.

But I need to have a way to reliably override materialize css selectively. I am pretty sure there are. But how?

Comment: it's not just about stylesheets. it's about selectors. `.row .col.s3` has higher priority over `.search_icon_div`. [Read this article about specificity on css-tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: The order, as well as the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the rules matters.

Comment: @Louy your comment is the most simple and straight forward answer (including explaining article) to my question. I would mark it as an answer I I could

Comment: @Delcon that's great! added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not just about stylesheets. it's about selectors. `.row .col.s3` has higher priority over `.search_icon_div`.

[Read this article about specificity on css-tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware of that styles are applied in cascading order

Correct

> they are not applied in the order they are loaded

Correct. Cascading order is not "the order they are loaded".

Well, it is, but that's the 4th and last determining factor which only gets used as a tie-break if the 3 previous factors all come out equal.

> But I need to have a way to reliably override materialize css selectively

Use earlier factors in [the cascade order rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order). The [specificity of the selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) is normally the one you want to change.

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than
>     a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an
>     element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no
>     selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID
>     attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes
>     and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element
>     names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
>
> The specificity is
>   based only on the form of the selector. In particular, a selector of
>   the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0,
>   c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the
>   source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a
>   large base) gives the specificity.

Answer (score 0):

> when I look at how they are applied at the DOM I see that they are not
>   applied in the order they are loaded.

Order of loading of CSS resources has nothing to do with specificity of selectors. Nothing at all.

But position of `<link>`s and `<style>` in the DOM does matter for order of how CSS rules are applied.

If two selectors have the same specificity then the rule that appeared "later in DOM order and in CSS file" is applied on top of another one.